# Baseball force play

Tags: rules, baseball

Bases loaded, nobody out. Ground ball to pitcher, throws home for out. Catcher throws to first and the runner on first never ran and is standing on first when the first baseman catches the ball. What is the call on the runner? The batter was called out because he didn't run either.

Answer (score 4):

This depends on the actions of the first baseman. The batter is not out until the first baseman touches first base or he gets tagged.

Case 1: The first baseman is standing on the base when he catches the ball, or catches the ball and then touches first base without tagging the runner. The batter is now out and this removes the force play on the runner on first. He no longer has to run to second. If he is standing on first base he is safe, if he is off the base he needs to be tagged to be out.

Case 2: The first baseman tags the runner on first before touching first base. The runner on first is forced to run to second by the batter, so when he is tagged he is out. The first baseman can then touch first base to retire the batter and complete the triple play.

Comment: Agreed with case 1, I'd like to see backup on case 2. My understanding is that the runner isn't forced to run to 2nd until the batter touches 1st.

Comment: Nevermind, you are correct on both. BTW, here's an article that seems to explain this if you want backup. http://m.providencejournal.com/sports/red-sox/content/20130623-confusing-play-at-first-base-proves-costly-for-red-sox.ece

Comment: I think [Rule 7.03](http://www.baseball-almanac.com/rule7.shtml) covers what happens if the runner never leaves the base before the batter reaches it in case 2. Allowing the runner to be tagged even while on the base protects the defense from losing an easily turned double play if the runner simply refuses to run.